# Is a question on BRDF databases permitted?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I have been researching measured Bi-directional Reflectance Distribution Function (BRDF) databases for real materials for a couple of days, and made a list of them with a short summary of each for another project. I'd like to share this knowledge with Internet users (and particularly the StackExchange community which has helped me out so many times).

Is this something I could put as a question and then answer it with the list of databases? Or would the community prefer that I put the information on another website (which will probably disappear into obscurity and may be difficult to find, or potentially not have the same longevity as a StackExchange Question and Answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be interested in reading your findings.

I think this is a good fit for this Q&A because the split *"this was the question/problem to answer"* vs *"this is a solution"* is also interesting in itself.